# How to convert an old form class with embedded designer code to separate partial classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, macros, windows-forms-designer

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669540/split-old-net-code-into-designer-partial-class) but the manual way takes forever and the macro is good but every time I run it all my event handlers get erased by Visual Studio when it parses the designer file. Also the macro is a bit old and places sections and functions in a different way than contemporary Visual Studio does so that's a bit annoying as well.

I have to do this to around 20 forms and every single one so far is taking over a half an hour (they're huge) and is prone to error because I may forget to relink something. Does anyone know of a better way? Or at least a way to make it so Visual Studio doesn't erase the event handlers when reparsing the designer file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the event handlers and other designer code didn't use the fully qualified namespaces and `this` for assignments. As a result, when Visual Studio parsed the designer code in the partial class, a lot of event handlers were erased because they weren't in the proper format.

The fix was to go through all the designer code beforehand and make sure `this` was used everywhere and that all classes were used with their fully qualified namespaces before running the macro script.